# Using as.Date in R to convert to dates and getting series of "NA"s

Tags: r, date, formatting, import-from-csv

Using the following code to try to get my date column into the right format, but it's just returning all of the dates as "NA".

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Files\\a")
data <- read.csv("file1.csv")

data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "d%/m%/Y%")
```

Edit: date values as follows: 11/09/2009

Comment: can you show us the 'Date' column values. probably the format that you are specifying here doesn't match

Comment: Try `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`.

Answer (score 3):

From the `?as.Date`documentation:

`If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific. The most common behaviour is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one. If it specifies a date incorrectly, reliable implementations will give an error and the date is reported as ‘NA’. Unfortunately some common implementations (such as ‘glibc’) are unreliable and guess at the intended meaning.`

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Select the tic mark over the solution - to make it as anwser, if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the date with the package lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
date <- parse_date_time(x = date,
                orders = c("d m y", "d B Y", "mdy"),
                locale = "eng")
```

After you may specify which format you want the date to be:

```
character_date <- as.character(as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```